# itextpfg 5.5.0 add watermark to existing pdf for printing only

Tags: itext, watermark

I am new to the PDF and have been working through examples and have understood the technology.  I want be able to print watermark on existing pdf, but not show it in viewing mode. I am using PdfStamper to read in the existing pdf and then adding PdfLayer using getUnderContent(pagenum) and adding the watermark the layer. I set the attributes of layer for print to be true and false to be visible.

When I try to print it, no watermark. Now I can hide the watermark and printed if I create new pdf, but on existing pdf.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Depending on your pdf the `Undercontent` may be completely covered by content. If you can share the document, wer can check.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What have you tried? Did you use an OCG to make sure the watermark is only visible when printing? Did you use the correct coordinates when adding the watermark (not all PDFs use the coordinate `(0, 0)` as the origin of the coordinate system)? Did you check if the existing content is opaque? Your question can't be answered without more info.